# Rust Addition Function from user input

Tags: io, type-conversion, rust

```
use std::io;

fn main(){
    let mut line = String::new();
    let input = io::stdin();

    println!("Enter First Number: ");
    input.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
    let num1 = line.parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    println!("Enter Second Number: ");
    input.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
    let num2 = line.parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    println!("Total = {}", get_sum(num1, num2));
}

fn get_sum(num1: i32, num2: i32) -> i32 {
    num1 + num2
}
```

Hello, in this code I am just trying to create a function that will add two numbers that the user inputs together. However after I type in the first number I get this error:

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', ../src/libcore\result.rs:785
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

Comment: Why not try doing matches instead of unwraps first? You're probably losing an error in all of those unwraps somewhere.

Comment: `read_line` includes the newline; see the answer to the question this is marked as a duplicate of for working code

Comment: @qDot `unwrap` doesn't "lose" errors. If there's an error, the program panics.

Comment: @DK. congratulations on the gold badge!